# Showing $\xi$ exists with certain restrictions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$
 f(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \frac{1}{n} & \text{if } x\in[0,1] \text{ and } x= \frac{m}{n},\ \gcd(m,n)=1\\
       0 & \text{if } x\in [0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}, \text{ or }x =0
     \end{cases}
$$
Show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ and every subinterval $I \subset [0,1]$, there exists $\xi \in I \cap \mathbb{Q}$ with $\xi = \frac{m}{n}$ s.t. $\gcd(m,n)=1$ and $f(\xi) < \epsilon$

I've noted that the number of elements $x \in\mathbb{Q}$ with $x = \frac{m}{n}$, $\gcd(m,n) =1$ and $|x|<1$ is finite. However, i'm not really sure how else to continue.

Answer (score 1):

Given any $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and any subinterval $I$, you have noted that the number of rationals with denominator $\leq N$ is finite. But since the rationals are dense, in particular, there are infinitely many in $I$, and so there must be one (call it $\xi$) with denominator $>N$. This is the $\xi$ that you are looking for.

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding since the "But since the rationals are dense..." sentence I think is contradicting the first sentence. The number of rationals with denominator $N$ with the restrictions listed is finite. But the rationals are dense in $I$...so I was wrong that they are finite?

Comment: The set of rationals in $I$ with denominator equal to a particular $N$ is finite, hence the set of rationals in $I$ with denominator $\leq$ to a particular $N$ is finite. But the set of all rationals in $I$ is infinite.